# How to perform conditional validation in html Angular form

Tags: angular, forms, maxlength, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-form-validation

I have a form where I want to implement the MAXLENGTH validation only if the value is not equal to 0.

So if `parameter.valueMaxlength === 0 { then dont execute maxlength validation }`
Is there a way to write this logic in the **html** file.

```
 <mat-form-field *ngSwitchCase="'TEXTBOX'" class="example-full-width">
  <input
    matInput
    [placeholder]="parameter.displayName"
    [formControlName]="parameter.id"
    [id]="parameter.id"
    [type]="parameter.dataType"
    [maxlength] = "parameter.valueMaxlength"

  />
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I think you can do `[attr.maxlength] = "yourcondition ? parameter.valueMaxlength : null"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following by using a ternary operator with `[attr.maxlength]`:

```
<input
    matInput
    [placeholder]="parameter.displayName"
    [formControlName]="parameter.id"
    [id]="parameter.id"
    [type]="parameter.dataType"
    [attr.maxlength]="parameter.valueMaxlength === 0 ? null : parameter.valueMaxlength" 
/>
```

`maxLength` will not render if what's passed is equal to `0`, otherwise it will render with a value equal to what's passed in.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkwrdz) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: works fine for me...!